# double pointer in loop

Tags: c, pointers

For the following example (from mysql source code), it uses Field **field. I am in trouble to think it as a 2 dimension array of Field.

```
typedef struct st_table_share  
{  
  .......  
  Field **field;           
  ....  
}  

for (Field **field=table->field ; *field ; field++)  
{  
    ...
```

Can I think it in this way, a table contains many rows and a row contains multiple columns/fields. So *field means a row, and **field mean a table?

If that's true, for the following code

```
for (Field **field=table->field ; *field ; field++)
```

it will exit when *field is null, so how could *field be null if *field is a row. Or can I say if a row has 5 columns, and field is the first column, then field+4 is the last column field, and field+5 is the end of the column which means null, so that the for loop will exit?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> So `*field` means a row, and `**field` mean a table?

In declaration syntax, yes.

> how could `*field` be null if `*field` is a row

If the authors of the code take care to preserve the invariant that `field` is terminated by a null pointer, as is done with `argv`. I.e., a table of *n* rows is an array of *n*+1 pointers, the last of which must always be null. This is a common C convention that obviates the need for an explicit count.

Comment: you are correct, I debug it in eclipse, and if create a table with 2 columns, *field is the first column, *(field+1) is the second column (based on the field name in the watch window), and *(field+2) =0x0. so 0x0 must be null. Sorry I am not good at C, I am a DBA.

Comment: @mysql guy: if you're writing C code, then don't use `0x0`. Use `0`, or the symbolic constant `NULL`, to denote a null pointer. `0x0` is confusing to C programmers.

Comment: I disagree with the "yes" part of this answer.  A variable of type `Field **` does not necessarily represent a two-dimensional array of Fields.  It could be a pointer to a one-dimensional array of pointers.  We can't really tell what it is without looking more carefully at the code.  If larsmans has looked carefully at the mysql source code then his answer could be right.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that `Field **` is a two-dimensional array?

A variable of type `Field **` does not necessarily represent a two-dimensional array of Fields.  It could be a pointer to a one-dimensional array of pointers to Fields.  Storing an array of *pointers* could be more convenient than storing an array of *structs* for several reasons: you can allocate the memory for the structs independently, you don't have to use memcpy to add a struct to the list, and certain list operations will be less expensive.  In fact, this is done in [libusb](http://libusb.sourceforge.net/api-1.0/group__dev.html), where a variable of type `libusb_device **` represents a (one-dimensional) list of usb devices.

Answer (score 0):

The loop will continue until "*field" is null.  i.e. the array should have a null-terminator (a non-existing row) at the end.

Answer (score 0):

> Or can I say if a row has 5 columns, and field is the first column, then field+4 is the last column field

Yes, but, you can say that

> and field+5 is the end of the column which means null

only if you initialized the array to be null-terminated.

And if you know how many columns your table has, you can iterate until you reach the last column instead of `; *field ;`.